# How to increase the size of Radwindow in Telerik

Tags: webforms, telerik

```js
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function GetRadWindow() {
                    var oWindow = null;
                    if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
                    else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
                    return oWindow;
                }
                function onClientClose(arg) {
                    // Pass the arguments from the dialog to the callback function on the main page.    
                    GetRadWindow().close(arg);
                }
                function OnClientClicked(sender, args) {
                    CloseWithRefresh();
                }
                function CloseWithRefresh() {
                    GetRadWindow().Close();
                }
            </script>
        </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

I want to resize my radWindow. how can i increase the radWindow size ?
And I've googled , i am not sure that why i have to use telerik:RadCodeBlock before script tag.
Note : i have not found any radwindow in my aspx file.

Answer (score 1):

Search in the whole project for Radwindow or RadWindowManager and once you find the control set its Width and Height properties.

You can also get a reference to the dialog and set its dimensions via JavaScript:

```
var oWnd = $find("<%= DialogWindow.ClientID %>");
oWnd.show();
//Here set the width and height of RadWindow
oWnd.setSize(400, 400);
```

This can be set also in the OnClientShow event of the window.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/set-radwindow-height-and-width-at-the-time-on-opning
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/client-side-programming/radwindow-object